# Insert data from nested list into separate table in rethinkdb

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I have a table with about 2m records with following structure:

```
{
    "fields": "values",
    "transactions": [
         {
              'from': '...',
              'value': '...'
         }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to separate the data in transaction field to be separate records in another table. Is there some native way to do it in rethinkdb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it using concatMap:

```
r.table('transactions').insert(
   r.table('records').concatMap(function (doc){return doc('transactions')})
)
```